# WORDPRESS: How to disable user confirmation e-mail based on new users prefix

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I have a platform on wordpress and I used the wp-login page as the registration page for new users. Regular registration works ok and users get their account activation mail.  The problem is when I enabled Facebook login, users do get registered but they get confirmation mail and those logged in with FB get confused cause usually FB login is immediate and require no password setup.

My FB plugin sets the prefix "facebook-" for every username. Can I base on the prefix to filter these users and just disable confirmation mail for FB registered users?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so strong with WP, but sure, you can. 
At part of code where email is sending (smt like email->send()) you can add if statement. Something like this:

```
private function registration()
{
    // some action here
    if(!isFacebookAuth($username)) {
        sendEmail();
    }
}

private function isFacebookAuth($username)
{
    if (strpos($username, 'facebook-') !== false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's a little bit bad solution, cause we solving the consequences of the problem, not the source, but will work fine, imho.

I'm sure that there is much better solution to divide FB and non-FB users at the beggining of registration, but you need to debug your source code and find it.